# Dereference a closure parameter

Tags: rust

The title might not be appropriate, be here is an example:

```
fn foo(impl Fn(&u32) -> bool) { ... }

foo(|x| *x < 100);
foo(|&x| x < 100);
```

Are the two closures passed to `foo` equivalent? I saw people use the second form in some places, but I couldn't find it in the official book. Is the `&x` part a destructure...?

Comment: Hi there! I closed this as dupe as this question has been asked a bunch of time already. In short: yes `&x` is part of a destructure and is equivalent to dereferencing (only works for `Copy` types). If you don't think the duplicates are correct as they don't answer your question, please let us know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns):

> *ReferencePattern* :
>
> (`&`|`&&`) `mut`? *Pattern*
>
> Reference patterns dereference the pointers that are being matched and, thus, borrow them.

So yes, they are equivalent.