# Double ampersand in filter closure

Tags: rust

I am working on rustling's [iterators5.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/iterators/iterators5.rs) and I came to see this solution for this function:

```
fn count_iterator(map: &HashMap<String, Progress>, value: Progress) -> usize {
    // map is a hashmap with String keys and Progress values.
    // map = { "variables1": Complete, "from_str": None, ... }
    // map.values().filter(|x| **x == value).count()
    map.values().filter(|x| x == &value).count()
}
```

As far as I understand it seems like `map.values()` is returning an iterator of references according to the documentation.

"An iterator visiting all values in arbitrary order. The iterator element type is &'a V."
See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.values

However, I am not sure why if I do `map.values().filter(|x|)`, Rust Analyzer recognizes `x` as a type `&&Progress`?

Is it because in `.filter()` and hence its closure, only takes in references of the values from the upstream chain? Therefore map.values() produces `&x` and .filter() only takes on references hence `&&x`.

I tried finding the documentation but I'm not sure where it says this:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter

**Edit: Follow up question**

Thanks for the comments for pointing out that `&Self::Item` means that the filter function is taking on a reference from the iterator.

My follow up question would be that since
`x` in `map.values().filter(|x|)` is of `&&Progress` type, why does `&x` make it a `&Progress` type? Is this some kind of double dereferencing?

And why does x in `x == &value` of `(|&x: &Progress| x == &value)` become `&Progress`?

I would have expected `x` to be still `&&Progress`

Comment: It says so right in the definition of the closure: `P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool` means that the closure must take in a reference to the x.

Comment: The signature has `where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`, and `Self::Item` is `&Progress`.

Comment: Thanks, now I know that `&Self::Item` means it is a reference

Comment: *if `x` is `&&Progress`, why does `&x` make it a `&Progress` type* - because `x` is a pattern, and in patterns `&` dereferences. You can think of it being a mirror image, so that `if let Some(x) = option` "strips" `Some()` off the option, so `&x` in a pattern "strips" the `&`, i.e. dereferences the value.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, is this behaviour covered under deref coercion? I am reading the docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types but I am not sure specifically which part is talking about this.

Comment: No, that's a [reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns) and has nothing to do with deref coercion.

Comment: Seems like another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832145/dereference-a-closure-parameter
also suggests that |&x| is a reference pattern, though I am not entirely sure what it means to be a reference pattern. 

Does it mean that as long as I use a & infront of a variable and some kind of matching is done its a reference pattern?

Comment: Please scroll up on my previous link and find the words "Patterns are used in:" along with a list where they are used, reference patterns are just a part of all patterns and yes, anything in a patternthat has a `&` is a reference pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the signatures of the `map` and `filter` methods of `Iterator`:

```
fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>
where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B;

fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P>
where
    Self: Sized,
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool;
```

The closure used by `map` takes ownership of values so that it can manipulate them, deconstruct them or use them as part of some new value. On the other hand, `filter`'s closure doesn't do anything with the items; it just needs to look at them in order to decide if they should be included or not, so it can take them by reference.

Some iterators are over values but some, like `HashMap::values`, are over references. That means the the associated `Item` type of the `HashMap::<T>::values` iterator is `&T`, not `T`. The closure supplied to `map` can accept `&T`, but the closure supplied to `filter` needs to accept `&&T`.

Rust's auto-deref and deref coercion rules mean that this is rarely a problem. You can mostly use a `&&T` or `&&&T` etc as if they were a `&T`.